# node_xslt documentation or examples not available

Tags: javascript, xml, node.js, xslt

**Hello,**

**I am new to xml, xsl, but I want to use node_xslt to Transform XML documents.**

I have seen the nodejs page for this https://www.npmjs.com/package/node_xslt and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XSLT/PI_Parameters, but it does not contains any example, so can someone provide me some link or examples through which I can understand about this..

Comment: Unfortunately, off-site recommendations are off-topic here.

Comment: Hi Mathias, sorry but i am really not able to understand what u want to say

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you very much , I have got answer of my question,

The Link http://www.tutorialspoint.com/xslt/xslt_syntax.htm is very useful,

I have require to do just the following

```
var xslt = require('node_xslt');

var document = xslt.readXmlFile('path of xml file');

var stylesheet = xslt.readXsltFile('path of xslt file');

var transformedString = xslt.transform(stylesheet, document, []);
```

This will give us the HTML by using xml and xslt, can be check by print this..

console.log("transformedString>>>>" + transformedString);

Comment: but I am till now not able to found, how I can use third parameter of xslt.transform(stylesheet, document, []);, please help...

Comment: in above code , according to documentation document is object, but when I am doing console.log("document>>>>"+JSON.stringify(document)),  it gives me only {}, can I get complete object????please help????